# How to Implement Many To Many for Spring and Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I would like to implement this relationship in Java Spring and Hibernate:
[image]

In my GnrlOrgChargeCode class, I have:

```
@OneToMany (targetEntity=IOrgChargeCodeCond.class, mappedBy="gnrlOrgChargeCode", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List <IOrgChargeCodeCond> orgChargeCodeConds;
```

and in my OrgChargeCodeCond class, I have:

```
@ManyToOne
private IGnrlOrgChargeCode gnrlOrgChargeCode;
    
@OneToMany
private List <IBillingCondition> billingCondition;
```

and in my BillingCondition class:

```
@OneToMany
private List <OrgChargeCodeCond> orgChargeCodeCond;
```

and in my OrgChargeCodeRule class:

```
@ManyToOne
private BillingRule billingRule;
```

and in my BillingRule class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "billingRule")
private List<OrgChargeCodeRule> orgChargeCodeRules;
```

But when I startup Tomcat, I get this error:

> Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: ORG_CHARGE_CODE_COND, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(billingCondition)]

My query is this:

```
select from GnrlOrgChargeCode gocc 
join OrgChargeCodeRule occr 
join BillingRule br 
join OrgChargeCodeCond occc 
join BillingCondition bc 
where gocc.orgId = ?
```

assuming gocc.orgId is valid and there are rows in gocc.

Please help. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think here is the problem:

```
OrgChargeCodeCond:
@OneToMany
private List <IBillingCondition> billingCondition;

BillingCondition:
@OneToMany
private List <OrgChargeCodeCond> orgChargeCodeCond;
```

So you are actually defining a @OneToMany relation in both directions. From your diagram the BillingCondition should have @ManyToOne.
If you need a many-to-many relationship, you can try to make this work with @ManyToMany annotations on both sides. But I wouldn't recommend it, better add another entity and create @OneToMany in between.

Another "pro tipp", have a look at https://bootify.io, you can create or import your schema and get out your Hibernate entities.

Comment: I have changed BillingCondition.java's to @ManyToOne private IOrgChargeCodeCond orgChargeCodeCond. But the error still persist. Please help.

Comment: Did you also change the field from List to single instance? It's really difficult to debug, but check out Bootify, it can help you (no registration)

Comment: Yes, I did. I changed List to "private IOrgChargeCodeCond orgChargeCodeCond". Should I change OrgChargeCodeCond.java's billingCondition to single instance too?
Please help. Thanks.